# BASH - Associative array - getting the value of the key in the final element

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have created an associative array as follows:

```
declare -A test_array

test_array[0,0]="1"
test_array[0,1]="A"
test_array[0,2]="11"
test_array[0,3]="AA"
test_array[1,0]="2"
test_array[1,1]="B"
test_array[1,2]="22"
test_array[1,3]="BB"
```

What I want to do is to get the value of the key in the final element. In this case, the 1 in:

```
test_array[1,3]="BB"
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no "final element" in an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

Associative array keys are not held in any given order. The usual solution to this problem is to have a second indexed array that holds the keys in the order you want to remember. Eg an array `x`:

```
declare -a x

test_array[0,0]="1" x[${#x[*]}]='0,0'
test_array[0,1]="A" x[${#x[*]}]='0,1'
...
```

`${#x[*]}` is the length of the `x` array, so each line above is adding a new entry
to the end of the `x` array (index 0, then 1, ...).

You can then use the last entry of this array (at index length-1) to get your key and value:

```
echo ${x[${#x[*]}-1]}
echo ${test_array[${x[${#x[*]}-1]}]}
```

Comment: Hi @meuh. The echo statement in your example gives me the value, rather than the key of the final item to be added. Is there any way of getting the key instead?

Comment: sorry, I went a step beyond what you asked for. The key is `${x[${#x[*]}-1]}`.